# jquery using $.on for added dom elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a bit confused, I have a bunch of elements that get added via jquery using a ajax call and I want to attach a click handler to them (there could be a lot).

But I have no idea how to even begin this, I looked at .on and it is really confusing. I want to attach a click event handler for a certain class so that when I click on it, I get the `this.id` and then do stuff with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called event delegation.

You want to set the event listener on a higher element in the DOM that'll never change, but only fire off the event handler if the child element that has been clicked matches a specific selector.

Here's how it's done with jQuery's `.on()`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.your-selector', function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

---

**P.S.** You could probably apply the event listener to an element lower down in the DOM tree...

Comment: This will work, but there are almost always better listeners than document. For the sake of an example it's OK because you know it will always work. But when Steven gets around to using this code, he should be aware that he should pick the closest ancestor element that doesn't get destroyed.

Comment: @Steven - better than what? This is your only option (unless you want to rebind the handler after every AJAX request). This is the correct way to do it (although, as mentioned, you should bind it to the lowest possible DOM node).

Comment: @Steven IF your "elements" are wrapped by another element with ID, then `$("#wrapper").on('click', '.your-selector', function(){` would be much faster I suppose!

Comment: @Steven IF you can change the `(document)` to something more specific, this would be better I would think, otherwise they should be equal performance.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the id of a clicked element with the class "test"...

```
$(".test").on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id")
});
```

You'll need to run that *after* the ajax call returns.  It will only bind the click event to elements that exist when it runs, so it's no good at document.ready.

Comment: So would yours or Joseph's answer be better performance wise?

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand.  See Joseph's answer for what?

Comment: @Steven - I do see an advantage with Joseph's version.  His will automatically work with new added elements, whereas my code would not.  If the ajax call is only run once, then my code is more suitable.  If it's run more than once then Joseph's code is more suitable.

Comment: @Joseph - See my comment above ;)

Comment: @Archer - Which is the whole point of event delegation (besides having 1 handler instead of multiple ones - one for each element matched).